# How to test Friends Data Permissions in Facebook Graph API Explorer

Tags: facebook, rest, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WteK95AppF4) from facebook explaining the Graph API Explorer tool, when user clicks on `Get Access Token`, one of the *tabs* in the top is titled `Friends Data Permissions`.

This is the image from the Video:
[image]

This is what I see currently in the [graph API Explorer tool online](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer): 
[image]

**Why is the option *Friends Data Permissions* missing?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That video is from 2013. Friend permissions have been removed with v2.0 of the API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0